# Dynamically hooking up a class having different possible constructors

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, constructor, instantiation

Let's say I have two classes that look like this:

```
public class ByteFilter
{
    private Func <int, byte[]> readBytes;
    private Action<byte[]> writeBytes;

    public ByteFilter(Func <int, byte[]> readBytes, Action<byte[]> writeBytes)
    {
        this.readBytes = readBytes;
        this.writeBytes = writeBytes;
    }
}

public class PacketFilter
{
    private Func<Packet> readPacket;
    private Action<Packet> writePacket;

    Public PacketFilter(Func<Packet> readPacket, Action<Packet> writePacket)
    {
        this.readBytes = readPacket;
        this.writeBytes = writePacket;
    }
}
```

Either class may be instantiated at runtime (via `Activator.CreateInstance`) to perform a filtering function.  The read and write methods will be hooked up at runtime to methods from other classes that will provide and accept byte arrays or packets.

Within each filter is additional code that performs the filtering function:

```
public void Process()
{
    while (!done)
    {
        byte[] data = ReadBytes();      // or ReadPacket()
        // perform filtering on data
        WriteBytes(data);               // or WritePacket()
    }
}
```

If *only one of the above constructor signatures will be present in each filter,* how do I determine (using Reflection) which constructor signature is present, so that I can hook up the appropriate methods at runtime?

Note: If I'm daffy and doing this the wrong way, I'd like to know that too.

Comment: You lost me on the second paragraph...  Maybe I'm not visualizing how you intend to use this properly.  What's the reasoning for using these Filter classes purely to hold delegates as opposed implementing a couple interfaces on the classes actually doing the work?  Is this actually a DI question?

Comment: [System.Type.GetConstructors()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e687hf0d.aspx)? Am I missing something?

Comment: Assuming you're using Activator already, dont you already know the type and have the arguments? What does the code for the instanciation look like?

Comment: @Pete: Basically, the classes hosting the filter will hook up their delegates using either the `Packet[]` constructor or the `Byte[]` constructor, so that they can push data into one side of the filter, and retrieve it from the other side. The filter will provide only one constructor variant for the hosting classes to use, not both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you do something like?

```
bool packetConstructor = 
            typeof(PacketFilter).GetConstructors()
                                .Any(c => c.GetParameters()
                                           .Any(p => p.ParameterType 
                                                    == typeof(Func<Packet>)));
```

replacing `typeof(PacketFilter)` with appropriate instance.

Comment: A very clever use of Linq, I think.

Answer (score 2):

An option that has not been mentioned is to use [Fasterflect](http://fasterflect.codeplex.com), a library created to make reflection easier and faster where possible.

It also has a couple of features built on top of the core reflection capabilities, one of which is the ability to construct objects when you don't know what constructors are available.

```
var instance = typeof(PacketFilter).TryCreateInstance( new { Foo = "Bar" } );
```

There are also overloads for passing in a dictionary of named values or discrete name and value arrays. The latest code also provides extensions for constructing objects just from an ordered list of values, matching them in order to parameters by their type.

Fasterflect will automatically pick the constructor with the most matching arguments. If it's unable to use a value it'll try to set a matching property after construction. And you have the option of requiring all values to be used.

Disclaimer: I'm a contributor to the project.

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate the constructors (to get the one constructor) and then enumerate the parameters of the constructor.  Since the parameters are expected to be generic types, you then need to enumerate the generic type parameters for each generic constructor parameter.  Note that all of this is very hacky and I would recommend finding a better solution.  Reflection is a powerful tool and using it introduces complexity; if there is a less complex solution (such as a factory pattern, perhaps), that would be preferable.  It's also possible that your need to solve this particular problem reflects excessive complication in your existing design.  If you simplify the original design, you may find that the technical problem goes away.

Comment: I'm already using the Factory pattern to determine which filter I'm going to instantiate, but the factory does not know ahead of time which constructor variant the filter has. Perhaps I need another field in the configuration for the factory, to indicate the constructor type? But that seems redundant, since I can reflect over the filter's members to figure out which constructor it has.